# Extremely high CPU usage when training a model on GPU

Tags: python, tensorflow

Recently I discovered something rather strange with the project that I worked on for quite a while already. The model I have is rather conventional: a convnet with a few fully connected layers. For data loading I use tf.data API, but the same thing happens with queue-based code that I had before porting to tf.data. After a few hours since the training of the model begins, the CPU usage rises to very high levels, 1500-2000% as reported by the `htop` util. And at the beginning of training everything is fine, the main process shows only about 200% CPU usage. Attached is the screenshot of the `htop` output, and another thing that's worrying is all the child processes that also have pretty high CPU load.

I am using tensorflow-gpu version 1.11, running it on NVIDIA Tesla V100. I am pretty sure that the model does run on the GPU and not on the CPU: nvidia-smi shows that GPU is occupied at an about 70% rate.

Obviously, I cannot ask for an exact cause of this, and it would be difficult to strip the problem down to a reproducible test case. However, may be you could point me at some debugging techniques that are applicable in such case.

[image: htop output]

Comment: Does increasing the swap space size make the problem go away?